# How to add custom sort by field in magento?

Tags: magento

I am using magento 1.5.0 so what should be added & where in Toolbar.php? inside Mage/Catalog/Product/List

Comment: can you please elaborate your question so far what have you done & were you

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the **Used for Sorting in Product Listing** flag to **Yes** while editing your custom attribute in Catalog, Attributes, Manage Attributes.
Regards, Alessandro

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, for your answer but the thing is i want to use entity_id, if u have any idea. So for that i am using 
<option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl('entity_id', 'desc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent('entity_id') && $this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
Newest to Oldest
</option>
But not working. Main thing is i have done above changes in my toolbar.phtml file.
So, Any Idea?